# Problems spreading out cells in UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm currently trying to space out some custom cells in a UICollectionViewFlowLayout with dynamically sized cells. What I'm finding out is that the spacing in between the cells is inconsistent. I've been reading up on the layout, and I've implemented all the delegate methods to control minimum sizing, but those seem to have no effect. Here is the view as it stands now

[image]

And here is my code for sizing:

In the layout and view delegate:

```
- (CGFloat) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (CGFloat) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Tag *tag = [[Search sharedManager] tagAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *labelText = tag[@"Name"];
    CGSize labelTextSize = [labelText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0f]}];
    return labelTextSize;
}
```

The custom cell

```
@implementation TagCellCollectionViewCell
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.tagBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0f];
        self.tagBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       // self.tagBtn.frame = CGRectMake(-frame.size.width/4+20, -frame.size.width/4+5, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);


       [[self.tagBtn layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f/255.0f green:99.0f/255.0f blue:74.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor]];
        [[self.tagBtn layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        self.tagBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.tagBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f/255.0f green:99.0f/255.0f blue:74.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.tagBtn];

    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

What am I missing here that will put a consistent amount of space between each cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the item being returned from

```
- (CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

was overlapping the minimumInterimSpacing value. Since I was looking for something with systemfontofsize = 8, I needed to ensure that my interim spacing went above that value. Setting it to the 5 I had above caused it to conflict in odd ways, setting it to 15 spaces the cells out evenly because the number of pixels in between the cells is greater than the calculated size.